# how to get date from text file and output only yyyy-mm-dd java

Tags: java

I'm trying to write simple program that reads text file and then outputs only date in `yyyy.MM.dd` format, into the console the problem is that I have in file some random strings  f.e. ppppp  2012-12-13   2012-13-06  po2012 I want only dates to be printed out

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        String fname = System.getProperty("user.home") + "/Test/dates.txt";
        File f = new File(fname);
        try {
            SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            format.setLenient(false);
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(f);

            ArrayList<String> da = new ArrayList<String>();
            while(sc.hasNext()) {
                da.add(sc.next());
            }
            for (int i = 0;i<da.size()-1; i++) {

                ParsePosition pp = new ParsePosition(0);
                Date d = (Date) format.parse(da.get(i), pp);
                if (d == null) {
                    System.err.println("Invalid date in " + da.get(i));
                    continue;}
                System.out.println(d);
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, so what's the problem? (Other than your indentation, which is making your post hard to read...)

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps

- Create 2 dataformat objects, one for parsing the dates from text file and the other for formatting the parsed date to print it in the new format
- Used Reader to read the dates line by line
- For each line (i.e. the date read)
  -- parse it
  -- reformat it
  -- print it to the console